# Combination/permutation on seating arrangements

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

> $32$ people are to be seated in a square table where each side $A, B, C,$ and $D$ has $10$ chairs. If five of the the people want to sit at side $A$ and another six want to sit at side $B$, how many ways can all of them be seated?

I'm not sure on how to approach this problem. Initially I did ${10 \choose 5}{10 \choose 6}{29 \choose 21}$ but this was said to be incorrect. Can someone help me out?

Comment: Just fix some of the $\binom{10}5$ possibilities for side $A$, and also fix some of the $\binom{10}6$ possibilities for side $B$. How many possibilities are now to distribute the remained people on (one - say $C$ - or equivalently) both remained sides?

Comment: I'd read a claim like,  "$5$ people want to sit on side $A$" as saying that "at least $5$ people must be on side $A$".    So you first need the number of $4-$tuples $(a,b,c,d)$ of non-negative inegers with $a+b+c+d=32$ and $5≤a≤10,6≤b≤10, c≤10,d≤10$.  Also, it's not clear to me whether or not the order of the people on a given side matters.   That needs to be specified.

Comment: You forgot the number of ways to choose the people from 32: $\binom{32}{5}\binom{27}{6}$

Comment: @lulu Oh, now it's clearer. What's the best way to accomplish this though without using generating functions?

Comment: The numbers are small, I'df just do case by case work.  Letting $A=a-5, B=b-6$ we jsut want $A+B+c+d=21$.  Stars and Bars basically works, but you have to deal with the caps. A little messy, but not really hard.

Comment: @lulu Just saw your edited comment now. I suppose the order of the people matters since I believe this is a permutation problem. Would the solution simply then be $P(10,5) \cdot P(10,6) \cdot P(29,21)$? Sorry for the bulk of questions.

Comment: No, that's not the answer.  As I said, as I read the problem you still have to count the ways to distribute the people on the sides.  You could have $8$ each on $A,B,C,D$ for instance, or $10$ each of $A,B,C$ with just $2$ on $D$. And so on.  there are a lot of possible distributions.  It's not a hard problem, but it is fairly messy.

Comment: Just to put it into perspective, there are $\binom {24}3=2024$ four-tuples $(A,B,c,d)$ which sum to $21$ if you ignore the caps.  In principle you could just write them all down and eliminate those that violate the caps, but that's not practical.  So you will have to be more systematic.

Comment: @lulu Yep but if we base from the $2024$ combinations alone it's not enough for the number of arrangements. I'm able to say this because the choices for this question actually included a lone combination (my answer, which was wrong) and three other choices including permutations (one of them being the latest answer I gave to you).

Comment: I don't understand.  I did not say that $2024$ was the answer.  It is not.  What I said was that this was the number of ways to populate (though not order) the sides IF you ignore the caps.  Of course, you can not ignore the caps.  My point was that number, while not really all that large, is too big to make it practical to simply enumerate them and cross off the bad ones.  You will need to think about more systematic ways to proceed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122534/discussion-between-shanic-and-lulu).

Comment: As I read the problem, it just says that $A,B,C,D,E$ need to sit somewhere on side **A**, and $F,G,H,I,J.K$ need  to sit somewhere on side **B**, and the rest can sit any which way.

Answer (score 1):

Seat the "special" people for side $A$ in $P(10,5)$ ways, the "special" people on side $B$ in $P(10,6)$ ways, and permute the balance in $P(29,21)$ ways

This assumes that people don't care whether they are clustered together or not, and that the "special" people for sides $A$ and $B$ are known

Comment: This count fails to take into account the fact that none of the sides can take more than $10$ people.

Comment: @lulu: I don't see how that comes into the picture. $5$ seats are vacant on **A**, $4$ on **B** and $10$ each on **C** and **D**, totaling $29$, with $21$ people to be seated. Surely a vacant seat is a vacant seat, whichever side it is on ? So $\binom{29}{21}21!$ arrangements ?

Comment: I don;'t understand. Suppose the people are $\{a_1, \cdots, a_{32}\}$ with $a_1,\cdots, a_5$ sitting on $A$ and $a_6, \cdots , a_{11}$ sitting on $B$.  My permutation is...just leave them all in numerical order.  How should those people seat?  What side does, say, $a_{12}$ sit on?

Comment: @lulu:$a_{12}$ is free to sit in *any* of the $29$ vacant seats. The sides have only been specified for $5+6$ people, the rest have no restrictions.

Comment: But then what difference does the permutation make?  $a_{12}$ could be seated between $a_1$ and $a_2$ in Row $A$, or $a_{12}$ could be seated next to $a_{11}$ in row $B$, or many other possibilities.  You haven't specified the seating arrangement in any way, nor have you taken the $10$ seat cap into account.

Comment: Ah, I think I am overthinking this.  All you are saying is that we choose $21$ seats from the available $29$ in an ordered way.  Yes, I think that makes sense.  Sorry for introducing confusion.

Comment: Always good to get your comments !